# adding column of uuid in postgresql using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, postgresql, uuid

i have 4 sheets in my excel which im importing into postgresql
i want to add column of UUID in tables

i have created column of UUID in every table but i have
no idea how data is going to import into that column

please help
uuid maybe auto increment using  loop  maybe

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:xxxxx@localhost:xxxx/my_xxxx')

def sheets(data,con,file):
        if(data=='Sheet1'):
            df1 = pd.read_excel(file,'Sheet1')
            df1.to_sql(name='table1', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
           
        elif(data=='Sheet2'):
            df2=pd.read_excel(file,'Sheet2')
            df2.to_sql(name='table2', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)

        elif(data=='Sheet3'):
            df3=pd.read_excel(file,'Sheet3')
            df3.to_sql(name='table3', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)

        elif(data=='Sheet4'):
            df4 = pd.read_excel(file,'Sheet4')
            df4.to_sql(name='table4', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)


xls = pd.ExcelFile('postgre.xlsx')
with pd.ExcelFile('postgre.xlsx') as  xls:
    for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names:
       sheets(sheet_name,engine,xls)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not import the UUID, let Postgres generate it by defining a default value on your table.  You will need either the extension  [pgcrypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html#id-1.11.7.34.9)  or [uuid-ossp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html) installed. Then

```
for pgcrypto:
alter table table_name alter column uuid_column_name set default generate_random_uuid();

for uuid-ossp: 
alter table table_name alter column uuid_column_name set default uuid_generate_v4();
```

Either may require you to specify the columns you are uploading as you do not include the uuid column in the spreadsheet. That should not be much a problem. (IMHO) You should be doing that anyway.